# To read an image from Android Emulator

Tags: java, android

This is my code to convert image file into byte array.

```
 public String GetQRCode() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    /*
     * In this function the first part shows how to convert an image file to 
     * byte array. The second part of the code shows how to change byte array
     * back to a image.
     */
    AssetManager mgr = mAppView.getContext().getAssets();
    InputStream in = mgr.open("www/Siemens_QR.jpg");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
     char[] buf = new char[20];
    isr.read(buf, 0, 20);
    isr.close();
    // byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    String abc = buf.toString();
    return abc;
}
```

Here I am converting an image file into byte array. I am able to do this. But when try to read this image file using the path ("sdcard/Download/Siemens_QR.jpg") stored in emulator then I am getting VM aborting error. Please suggest me the correct path to read the image file stored in the emulator.

Comment: Hopefully, the way you'd do it in the emulator is identical to the way you'd do it on a hand-set or tablet.  If so, the issue is not 'how to do it in the emulator?' but 'how to do it?'.

Comment: are you trying to run this from IDE emulator...?

Answer (score 0):

if you have jpg image stored on SD card then get the file path and try to convert the image to byte using following method...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file path);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);

byte[] byte_img_data = baos.toByteArray();
```